# Tracking http request during it's life-cyle in akka-http

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I want to be able to track requests with an unique id in a log file. The best way I managed to do it is this way but this means that for each request a new exceptionHandler, rejectionHandler, routes and logRequestTimeRoutes will be instantiated. Something like it shouldn't be done for each request.

```
def exceptionHandler(id: UUID) = ExceptionHandler {
  case t =>
    val error = ErrorMessage(id.toString, 500, "Internal server error.")
    complete((InternalServerError, error))
}

def rejectionHandler(id: UUID) = RejectionHandler.newBuilder()
  .handleNotFound {
    val error = ErrorMessage(id.toString, 404, "Not found.")
    complete((NotFound, error))
  }
  .result()

def logRequestTimeRoutes(): Route = { ctx =>
  val id = UUID.randomUUID()
  val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
  // handling rejections/exceptions here so that we get proper status codes
  val innerRejectionsHandled = handleRejections(rejectionHandler(id))(routes(id))
  val innerExceptionsHandled = handleExceptions(exceptionHandler(id))(innerRejectionsHandled)
  mapResponse { resp =>
    // logRequestTime(id, end-start)
    resp
  }(innerExceptionsHandled)(ctx)
}

def routes(id: UUID) = {
  path("some" / "path") {
    get {
      val future = ??
      onSuccess(future) {
        case result => complete(result)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to pass a custom object through request life-cycle or inject it in RequestContext so I can extract it something like this in the exceptionHandler or rejectionHandler.

```
val exceptionHandler = ExceptionHandler {
  case t =>
    extractMyCustomObject { obj =>
      val error = ErrorMessage(obj.id.toString, 500, "Internal server error.")
      complete((InternalServerError, error))
    }
}
```

I'm using akka version "2.4.7"

Comment: Stick a custom header on the request at the top of the routing tree that represents the request id. Then you can re-access this header elsewhere in the code when/if you need to identify the request.

Comment: This is also an option. In this case it seems ok to do it. Thanks!